# Can someone pls help me solve this issue

Tags: javascript

Create a function fizzBuzz to return 'Fizz', 'Buzz', 'FizzBuzz', or the argument it receives, all depending on the argument of the function, a number that is divisible by, 3, 5, or both 3 and 5, respectively.

When the number is not divisible by 3 or 5, the number itself should be returned

Comment: Just search for fizzbuzz, there's several solutions to this (homework) problem

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried? Stackoverflow is not a code generation factory.

Comment: do you mean like this `return ( number % 3  != 0 || number % 5  != 0 ) ? number : 0;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to solve this exercise. One possible fizzBuzz function:

```
function fizzBuzz(number){
  return number % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : number % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" :
  number % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : number;
};
```

This is how to test it:

```
alert(fizzBuzz(10));
alert(fizzBuzz(60));
alert(fizzBuzz(6));
alert(fizzBuzz(7));
```

I recommend trying the [W3Schools JavaScript tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp), it is easy to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1; i <= 20; i++) {
    if (i % 15 == 0)
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
    else if (i % 3 == 0)
        console.log("Fizz");
    else if (i % 5 == 0)
        console.log("Buzz");
    else
        console.log(i);
}
```

from here: https://gist.github.com/jaysonrowe/1592432

Comment: @AndreaDusza Look at you making a point of something that is clearly not a point.